# Creating and storing a set # of class objects from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

I am making a game scoring calculator that needs to be able to prompt a user for the number of players, and then ask for each players information, storing it for each round of scoring.

The problem I have currently is how to write out a user input prompt that creates the number of `Player` objects given and then assigns each newly created object its own callable variable (preferably it would print the entered player name).

I have tried to use input that creates an input loop based on the given number but it only asks for input without storing anything.

Here is my `Player` class:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, inca, power, power_mask, short, medium, long):
        self.name = name
        self.inca = inca
        self.power = power
        self.power_mask = power_mask
        self.short = short
        self.medium = medium
        self.long = long
```

Would it be best to somehow write a `def` that creates a class object with all of parameters I need it stored under?
If so how would I write this out?

Comment: Not that when your write posts (questions or answers) you can scroll down from the editor window and see what it will actually look like when posted.

Comment: Terminology note: you mean *class instances*. The class object is `Player`, instances of the class object would be something like `p1 = Player()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something along these lines, you can create a dictionary that contains all the instances, then you can call on them by name for whatever purpose you need.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, inca, power, power_mask, short, medium, _long):
        self.name = name
        self.inca = inca
        self.power = power
        self.power_mask = power_mask
        self.short = short
        self.medium = medium
        self.long = _long

n = int(input('Enter amount of players: '))
d = {}
for i in range(n):
    name = input('Enter name: ')
    inca = input('Enter inca: ')
    power = input('Enter power: ')
    power_mask = input('Enter power mask: ')
    short = input('Enter short: ')
    medium = input('Enter medium: ')
    _long = input('Enter long: ')
    d[name] = Player(name, inca, power, power_mask, short, medium, _long)

print(d['vash'].power)
```

> ```
> Enter amount of players: 1   
> Enter name: vash
> Enter inca: rnation
> Enter power: over 9000
> Enter power mask: off
> Enter short: comings
> Enter medium: ...
> Enter long: oh yeah
> over 9000
> ```